# Typescript not showing that an object is nullable

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue with typescript where types with `| null` does not show as nullable. You can see the example below where I have the type

```
type A = {
    b: {
        c: number;
        d: string;
    } | null;
};
```

and then when I hover over `b` it does not show that it is nullable, and indeed when i use the type other places, it does not tell me that it could possibly be null

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I'd willing to bet that your [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) flag is disabled. Please share your tsconfig.json file

Comment: That was it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please enable [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) in your `tsconfig`.

You can use `"strict":"true"` too enable most of strict rules. The more strict rules are active - more safer your application is.